# Unable to upload Development APNs certificate

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm unable to upload the Dev APNs Certificate for cloud messaging, all I get is the error:

> There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again.

I've tried on different accounts and on different projects. Earlier today it seemed to be working fine.

Comment: I am facing the same problem

Comment: me to. Prod certificates works fine, Dev unable to upload

Comment: I'm facing this problem too

Comment: Me 5th, I have no idea what is going on, I have uploaded a production certificate on, but the development is not going!!

Comment: I'm not even able to upload a production certificate says: "The Bundle ID in the certificate does not match the Bundle ID you entered."

Comment: I got it. I guess it was a kind of instability. Changed nothing and worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue last night. My Dev APNs are gone and can't re-upload, i got the same error as you.

And immediately send and feedback / ticket to Firebase Support. It's an issue from their end, and already fixed and pushed to production they said.

Now my Dev APNs are back.

Here's the latest reply from Firebase Support Team

> Hello Bagus,
>
> This issue has been fixed from our end and the fix has been pushed to
> production. You should be able to upload the Development APNs
> certificates without issues.
>
> Although, feel free to let us know if the issue persists or if you
> have any additional questions we can help with.
>
> Thank you for using Firebase! Karishma

Answer (score 0):

I think I've Identified the problem, seems like Apple is now calling signed certs "Apple Push Services: #Bundle-Name" rather than "Apple Development iOS Push Services: #Bundle-Name". I'm guessing the guys at Firebase have yet to account for this.

I've sent them a bug report and will update this once I get a concrete response.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are facing some Issues to upload Development certificate on firebase -> go to console -> Select your respective project -> Project overview setting (gear sign) -> Project setting -> Cloud messaging -> iOS app configuration -> APNs certigicate -> upload the development certificate -> while uploading if you are facing issue to unable to read certificate just follow below steps.

1. Go to apple developer account -> Go to certificates, Id & profiles -> Identifier -> App Ids -> Check with the bundle is and check is the push Notification is enabled or not for development.

2.) If it is showing configured then please edit and enable the push notification.
For edit please refer below steps

- [image: Go to edit]
- After click edit -> Go to Push Notification section -> Click on Create certificate in Development SSL Certificate.
- Click on continue on create a CSR File page
- Upload CSR File
- Click on continue
- Now when you check after this setup the push notification show enabled (Please refer scren shot)
- [image]

- Now download certificate and double click.
- In keychain go to development certificate -> right click and Export it **without private key**.
- Now upload this .p12 file on firebase -> firebase -> go to console -> Select your respective project -> Project overview setting (gear sign) -> Project setting -> Cloud messaging -> iOS app configuration -> APNs certigicate -> upload the development certificate.